# Fail to evaluate script: when I upload a map/reduce script I received the error behind

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Error
Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"syntax error (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#11)","stack":[]}

I'm very new at suitescript, so, I wanted to know how a map/reduce script works and I copy the documentation example and I received that error.

```
define(['N/file'], (file) => {
const PUNCTUATION_REGEXP = /[\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#\$%&\(\)\*\+,\-\.\/:;<=>\?@\ 
[\]\^_`\{\|\}~]/g;


function getInputData() {
return 'the quick brown fox \njumps over the lazy dog.'.split('\n');
}


function map(context) {

for (let i = 0; context.value && i < context.value.length; i++) {
  if (context.value[i] !== ' ' && !PUNCTUATION_REGEXP.test(context.value[i])) {

    context.write({
      key: context.value[i],
      value: 1,
    });
  }
}
}


function reduce(context) {

context.write({
  key: context.key,
  value: context.values.length,
});
}


function summarize(context) {

log.audit({
  title: 'Usage units consumed',
  details: context.usage,
});
log.audit({
  title: 'Concurrency',
  details: context.concurrency,
});
log.audit({
  title: 'Number of yields',
  details: context.yields,
});


let text = '';
let totalKeysSaved = 0;
context.output.iterator().each((key, value) => {
  text += (`${key} ${value}\n`);
  totalKeysSaved++;
  return true;
});

log.audit({
  title: 'Unique number of letters used in string',
  details: totalKeysSaved,
});


const fileObj = file.create({
  name: 'prueba_mapReduce_training_lk.txt',
  fileType: file.Type.PLAINTEXT,
  contents: text,
});

fileObj.folder = -15;
const fileId = fileObj.save();


log.audit({
  title: 'Id of new file record',
  details: fileId,
});
}

return {
getInputData,
map,
reduce,
summarize,
};
});
```

`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of Netsuite Suitescript isn't completely same as Javascript.

Things that were causing issues are -

- Don't use **let** while defining a variable.
- Output Iterator Loop will have some better syntax. (Use of => was giving error.) **Please make sure of (`${key} ${value}\n`) cause its giving error. Substituted with 0 for time being**

  ```
  CORRECT SYNTAX-

  context.output.iterator().each(function(key, value){
      text += 0; //Some issue with (`${key} ${value}\n`) [BAD SYNTAX]
      totalKeysSaved++;
      return true;
    });
  ```
- Always include JSDoc

  ```
  /** 
      *@NApiVersion 2.x 
      *@NScriptType MapReduceScript 
  */
  ```
- Follow the rules for return statement

  ```
  return {
    getInputData:getInputData,
    map:map,
    reduce:reduce,
    summarize:summarize,
  }
  ```

Above were the issues I found, please use the below code and test. Worked for me.

```
/** 
   *@NApiVersion 2.x 
   *@NScriptType MapReduceScript 
*/

define(['N/file'], function(file) {
    
    PUNCTUATION_REGEXP = /[\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#\$%&\(\)\*\+,\-\.\/:;<=>\?@\ [\]\^_`\{\|\}~]/g;
    
    function getInputData() {
    return 'the quick brown fox \njumps over the lazy dog.'.split('\n');
    }
    
    
    function map(context) {
    
    for (i=0; (context.value && i) < context.value.length; i++) {
      if (context.value[i] !== ' ' && !PUNCTUATION_REGEXP.test(context.value[i])) {
    
        context.write({
          key: context.value[i],
          value: 1,
        });
      }
    }
    }
    
    
    function reduce(context) {
    
    context.write({
      key: context.key,
      value: context.values.length,
    });
    }
    
    
    function summarize(context) {
    
    log.audit({
      title: 'Usage units consumed',
      details: context.usage,
    });
    log.audit({
      title: 'Concurrency',
      details: context.concurrency,
    });
    log.audit({
      title: 'Number of yields',
      details: context.yields,
    });
    
    
    text = '';
    totalKeysSaved = 0;
    context.output.iterator().each(function(key, value){
      text += 0; //Some issue with (`${key} ${value}\n`) [BAD SYNTAX]
      totalKeysSaved++;
      return true;
    });
    
    log.audit({
      title: 'Unique number of letters used in string',
      details: totalKeysSaved,
    });
    
    
    const fileObj = file.create({
      name: 'prueba_mapReduce_training_lk.txt',
      fileType: file.Type.PLAINTEXT,
      contents: text,
    });
    
    fileObj.folder = -15;
    const fileId = fileObj.save();
    
    
    log.audit({
      title: 'Id of new file record',
      details: fileId,
    });
    }
    
    return {
    getInputData:getInputData,
    map:map,
    reduce:reduce,
    summarize:summarize,
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use let if you specify @NApiVersion 2.1

Comment: @Brian Duffy Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

See the tags below, they are required for Map/Reduce script:

/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType MapReduceScript
*/